# YouTube API: How do I specify latest protocol version when using `gdata` in Python?

Tags: python, api, youtube

I'm using the Python [`gdata`](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) package to interface with YouTube. I want it to use the latest protocol version. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `gdata` currently doesn't support YouTube protocol 2 yet.

Answer (score 1):

[gdata.youtube.client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/youtube/client.py) uses a hard-coded api_version of 2, so you really have no choice to use any different version. However, version 2 [is the latest version](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_audience.html).

Comment: People are saying it's wrong on the YouTube-API forum: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/forum/discussion.html?place=msg%2Fyoutube-api-gdata%2FCMEn_CdLo4g%2Fl1H-ZVIi3yIJ

Comment: Ok, so in the light of this response, the correct answer to your question would be "develop patches to gdata to make it use version 2 fully".